# Integrating Nagios with a ticketing/incident management system

Tags: monitoring, nagios

Is there a free ticketing system/incident management system which will help me in achieving the following?

1) If a service goes down then Nagios alerts the on-duty staff and pushes the status to some backend or DB as a ticket, say the initial status is `"New"`.

2) The on-duty staff logs in through a frontend and acknowledges the new ticket by marking it as `"In progress`", so now the status of the ticket changes from `"New"` to `"In progress"`.

3) If even after "n" number of minutes no person from on-duty staff has changed the ticket status to `"In progress"` then Nagios alerts the next level of contacts. Although if the on-duty staff has acknowledged the ticket then there is no need to alert the next level.

4) When the service comes up Nagios closes the ticket by marking it "`Closed"`

Now I already have Nagios monitoring set up and currently it alerts by sending text messages and mails, what I'm looking for is some framework which only escalates the issue(alerts the second level) if the first level(on-duty staff) fails to respond to the initial alert.

By "responding to the alert" I mean, the on-duty staff can login via some frontend and basically change the status to something like `"Acknowledged"` or `"In progress"`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The nagios web front end is capable of implementing this minimal work flow using nagios acknowledgements, but it's not what I would call a ticketing system.

Any ticketing system that has a programmable API should be able to do what you want. The key nagios concepts that you'll need to understand to implement this are

**escalations** - Nagios uses these to send alerts to other users if a problem has not been acknowleged.

**event_handlers** - These are scripts that take actions when a service has a change in status.

**passive checks** - These are checks that don't do anything, but simply wait for recieved messages and alert based on the status in those messages.

All of these concepts are documented in the standard nagios documentation.

I'm fairly sure that you could do this with RT https://www.bestpractical.com/rt/, but that's just because I am familiar with it. This should be possible with any request tracker system that has an API interface for modifying ticket status.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, I searched around and found that Nagios can be integrated with RT, OSTicket. I'll give it a try.